# PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR: cannot drop table reports because other objects depend on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, drop-table

to give a bit of background. I’m a newbie in Ruby on Rails and I’m making a review website where users can report a review. I played around with having a ‘reportable’ polymorphic association and then reports table. Later I deleted the ‘reports’ table and created another reports table. The earlier migration was not allowing to create a new reports table migration, so I added ‘1’ next to the name of the migration earlier migration.

```
20180311071357_create_reports_1.rb
class CreateReports1 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.string :reason
      t.text :description
      t.string :email
      t.belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Fast forward to the present time. I didn’t do a production commit to Heroku for some time and I was just building the app. When I pushed to heroku, I’m getting the following error-

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --trace

Running rake db:migrate --trace on ⬢ housereview... up, run.6689 (Free)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
   (4.0ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(2386658352535867725);
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

Migrating to DeleteReports1 (20180318091834)
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN
== 20180318091834 DeleteReports1: migrating ===================================
-- drop_table(:reports)
   (2.8ms)  DROP TABLE "reports"
   (2.6ms)  ROLLBACK
   (2.3ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2386658352535867725)

rake aborted!

StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table reports because other objects depend on it

DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_cfc8432c20 on table notes depends on table reports

HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP TABLE "reports"
...
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table reports because other objects depend on it

DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_cfc8432c20 on table notes depends on table reports

HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP TABLE "reports"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'

.......
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table reports because other objects depend on it

DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_cfc8432c20 on table notes depends on table reports

HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
```

This is my schema-

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180407122611) do

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "address"
    t.string "street_number"
    t.string "locality"
    t.string "postal_code"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "route"
    t.string "state"
  end

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "report_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["report_id"], name: "index_notes_on_report_id"
  end

  create_table "reports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "reason"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "review_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.index ["review_id"], name: "index_reports_on_review_id"
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "duration"
    t.text     "positive"
    t.text     "negative"
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "rating_safety"
    t.integer  "rating_neighbour"
    t.integer  "rating_owner"
    t.integer  "rating_school"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "rating_overall"
    t.boolean  "blocked"
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_location_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "locality"
    t.string   "state"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

I tried (almost) everything to fix the issue. The following things I’ve tried so far-
-   Deleted the production app and then restore pgbackup
-   Delete the production app and then tried to do a fresh ‘git push heroku master’ and then ‘heroku run rake db:migrate’
-   Tried drop table command and then pushing code again and rake db:migrate
-   Tried ‘DROP TABLE if exists reports cascade;’ in pgsql

All the above had no luck.
The app works perfect in dev (SQLite) but heroku is not letting me rake db:migrate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Notes table contains report_id as foreign key so you did not able to drop reports table. You can do by using `dependent: :destroy`
In report.rb file change below line

```
has_many :notes
```

to

```
has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: @FA You can generate one migration for removing report_id from notes table and create this migration before drop table migration. so this migration will remove report_id from notes table and then you can drop reports table

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the migration that created the `notes` table around? I would guess that the `create_table :notes` in that migration won't exactly match what you're seeing in your `db/schema.rb`.

No matter, your problem is that the `notes.report_id` references `reports.id` via a foreign key inside the database. This foreign key was probably created by a `t.references :report, foreign_key: true` in a migration to ensure referential integrity (i.e. the database will ensure that any value in `notes.report_id` references something in the `reports` table). This foreign key constraint is preventing you from dropping the `reports` table as that would violate the constraint on `notes.report_id`.

I don't think you actually want to delete the `reports` table at all. Instead, you want to make the `reports` table at Heroku match what `schema.rb` says. Migrations aren't meant to last forever so go ahead and delete the offending migrations and write a new one that brings the `reports` table at Heroku in sync with what `schema.rb` says.

Once you have this mess cleaned up, there are two things you'll want to do:

1. Never rename migrations again. Delete old migrations and add new ones now and then. If you want to keep an old one around but use its name for something else then put a suffix on the *new* migration but really, there's no reason to keep old migrations around forever.
2. Install PostgreSQL in your local development environment. You should always be developing, testing, and deploying with the same stack. There are so many differences between databases that ActiveRecord won't protect you from that using different databases in the three environments is madness and little more than a short cut to pain and suffering.

Comment: The last two tips are gold. My 6 month younger me needed to have a chat with you earlier. I think I'm getting the mistake I've made and correct me if I'm wrong. 1) I created a `reports` table, then created a `notes` table. 2) `reports` and `notes` had 1-to-many association. 3) I pushed to Heroku. 4) Then I deleted my `reports` table in dev environment. 5) I then recreated the `reports` table. 6) Heroku push is now showing error because `notes` table is referring to the previous reports table? **solution-** drop `report_id` and recreate `report_id` column in `notes` table?

Comment: That sounds about right. If you don't care about the data then dropping the `notes.report_id` column will remove the FK as well. You'd do that in a migration *before* dropping the `reports` table.

Comment: still no luck. getting the same error. I've dropped both `reports` and `notes` table. And still getting this error- `== 20180318091834 DeleteReports: migrating ====================================
-- drop_table(:reports)
   (2.9ms)  DROP TABLE "reports"
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK 
PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table reports because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_cfc8432c20 on table notes depends on table reports`

Comment: You could manually `connection.execute('alter table notes drop constraint fk_rails_cfc8432c20')` as sort of a last resort. You could also delete the offending migrations, look at the table structure in production, and then add a new migration to sync them up.